# GCC noexcept compilation flag

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc

Is there a flag for GCC that enforces the compiler to optimize all function as if they were marked with the`noexcept` specifier?

Comment: Wy do you ask? In principle the performance of code not using exceptions does not cost even without `noexcept`.

Comment: `-fno-exceptions` will be the closest, but not exactly that.